# Moderator message reply copies user's response, instead of signature; Carpal Tunnel Lawsuit?

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools, moderator-messages

When we get a response to a moderator message, our box to reply to that response used to contain the default signature and a placeholder for our text. For the past couple days, however, it contains a copy of the user's last message to us. After just now testing on Meta, it seems this is not happening here; only on Stack Overflow.

Additionally; when preparing to send a *new* moderator message, before selecting the template to send, the message box is being displayed, and if the user had replied to *any* previous moderator message, that text is there. Once a template is selected, it is properly displayed, though.

As a result, I must now *manually* type this each time I reply:

> Regards, 
>   Andrew Barber 
>   Stack Overflow Moderator

This clearly could cause [Carpal Tunnel Syndrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carpal_tunnel_syndrome), and I love Stack Exchange too much to have to sue for it, once it occurs. Either that, or I am simply posting this so that I can prove Stack Exchange was made aware of the problem... ;)

I refrained from posting screenshots because I'm not sure they would have made sense without showing the private information contained in a message where it has happened.

Comment: Ah the problems of the ruling class.

Comment: It's to get you to stop sending out so many mod messages!

Comment: @bluefeet Hmmm... you might be correct, there! ;)

Comment: Oh, come on, it's not like you don't get a chuckle every time you write "Andrew Barber, Stack Overflow Moderator". ;P

Comment: @Yannis http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c1JHI7c-Id8

Comment: @Yannis It's more like a maniacal laugh, but point taken... bwahahahahahaHAHAHAAAA!!!11!!one!!1!11eleven!

Comment: @Asad One problem of the ruling class is the ruling of the problem class.

Comment: @Andrew Barber. that was a rather nice maniacal laugh - this mad physicist approves

Comment: @Andrew Try sending a message to me - then you can post screenshots :)

Comment: @Undo Not a good idea: Mod messages leave a permanent black mark on your account and they generate a lot of paperwork, they are also sent to every other moderator of the site and to SE. [Learn from my mistakes](http://stackoverflow.com/election/4#comment-21201737).

Comment: I checked, and it appears to use the last reply whether it was sent by the user or by the moderator. As a side note, I experience this with the answer field occasionally when I edit (or cancel an edit on) an existing answer - wonder if it's in any way related...

Comment: @Yannis Ooh - thanks! Really, though, there should be a 'do not scar this user for life' checkbox. Just sayin' :)

Comment: @Undo of course, you could always just break some rule... (just kidding!)

Comment: @Andrew Barber Let's see... Ah, this looks like a good place to Retag all of these [android] questions to [printer] and [c#]. Would that do it?

Comment: @bluefeet You were kidding above, of course, but I just looked at the mods stats on SO for the last quarter, and now I am wondering if this is status-by-design for me, only! ;)

Comment: @AndrewBarber Put down the moderator messages!

Comment: @Undo [printer] and [c#]; yeah, that would do it! (For the record, I suspect this may have been fixed.)

Comment: @bluefeet Next, you'll be telling me to go play outsude!

Comment: @AndrewBarber Now we know why you wanted to be a mod, it wasn't to clear flags...it was to send mod messages... _cue evil laugh_

Comment: @bluefeet BWAHAHAHAHAHAHA!!!!!1!!1one!!11!eleven1!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When I added draft support to moderator messages, I accidentally made it half work for non-moderator responses.  The working half was the "save a draft" part.

Since the draft never got cleared, it was always pre-populating the form when a moderator went to send a follow up message.

User responses no longer get drafts (they weren't intended to in the first place*), just messages being composed by moderators.

This fix went out with the last deploy.

<sub>*The main point of moderator message drafts is to allow moderators to show a draft message to another moderator for input, which is a tad different use case than question and answer drafts</sub>