# Android app custom "Off Topic" should include the "This question appears to be off-topic because it is about" pre-entered text

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, android-app, custom-close-reasons

When closing from the web (mobile or full) and choosing the custom off-topic reason, the box is pre-filled with:

> This question appears to be off-topic because it is about

This is quite helpful in the "[avoiding carpal tunnel syndrome lawsuits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182442/moderator-message-reply-copies-users-response-instead-of-signature-carpal-tun)" arena.

The Android app, however, does not do this. Given that it's a little bit harder to enter text on a phone or tablet than a full keyboard on a computer, this would be useful.